# Change elements in a directive template based on scope data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a directive nested within an ng-repeat. The ng-repeat item is passed to the directive. I am attempting to generate a directive template (for testing) or templateUrl with variable elements based on a key/value in the item passed to the directive. Essentially, if item.number > 50 make the button red else make it blue.

I may be using the wrong tool to solve the problem. The goal is to use something like this to change Bootstrap tags. For instance the logic:

```
if item.number > 50: 
  class="btn btn-danger"
else:
  class="btn btn-success"
```

If possible I'm trying to solve this with using templateUrl: as I'd like the button to launch a bootstrap modal and that's a lot to fit into the basic template option. It's much cleaner to pass the template individual scope variables.

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidcapatch/zkp9gmmd/3/) that tries to describe the problem.

html

```
<div ng-controller="TableCtrl">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Button</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="item in buttons">
        <td>{{item.id}}</td>
        <td new-button item='item'></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

app.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function TableCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.buttons = {
    button1: {
      id: 1,
      number: '10',
    },
    button2: {
      id: 2,
      munber: '85',
    }
  };
};

myApp.directive('newButton', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      item: '=',
    },
    link: function(elem, attrs, scope) {
        // This is most likely not the right location for this
        /*if (item.number > 50) {
        button.color = red
      }, else {
        button.color = blue
      }; */
    },
    template: '<td><button type="button">{{button.color}}</button></td>'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can use an `ng-class` for this:

```
<button ng-class="{
  'btn-danger': item.number > 50,
  'btn-success': item.number <= 50
}"></button>
```

See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Comment: You are correct, ng-class works for the class portion. My follow up issue then is when using Angular UI Boostrap progress bars, they moved the color out of the class and made it's own type="" element. Is there a way to do similar logic with their custom element?

    <uib-progressbar value="55" type="info"></uib-progressbar>

Comment: `<uib-progressbar value="55" type="{{item.number > 50 ? 'btn-danger' : 'btn-success'}}"></uib-progressbar>`

Comment: That'll do it! Getting lost in the documentation you miss the little/simple things. Thankyou kindly.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need a custom directive you could try using it like this

`link: function(scope,elem,attrs) {
        var item=scope.item;
        if (item.number > 50) {
        elem.addClass("btn-danger");
      } else {
        elem.addClass("btn-success");
      }
    }`

But I think that for what you're trying to achieve it's better to use the ngClass directive as follows:

```
<button type="button" item="item" class="btn" ng-class="item.number > 50?'btn-danger':'btn-success'"></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your example code, there are a few points to note:

1. Typo in button 2's 'munber' property.
2. The link function doesn't use dependency injection, so the order of the arguments does matter. Scope needs to be moved first.
3. Your commented out bit of code is close to working, but you need to address the variables as properties of scope - item is on scope, and the button object you are creating needs to be created on scope in order to be addressed as 'button.' from your view template.

This works (it would be better, as others have said, to use ng-class, rather than class plus moustache syntax, but I wanted to stay as close to your code sample as possible):

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="TableCtrl">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Button</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="item in buttons">
        <td>{{item.id}}</td>
        <td new-button item='item'></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function TableCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.buttons = {
    button1: {
      id: 1,
      number: '10',
    },
    button2: {
      id: 2,
      number: '85',
    }
  };
};

myApp.directive('newButton', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      item: '=',
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        scope.button = {};
        if (scope.item.number > 50) {
        scope.button.class = 'btn btn-danger';
      } else {
        scope.button.class = 'btn btn-success';
      };
    },
    template: '<td><button type="button" class="{{button.class}}">Press Me?</button></td>'
  }
});
```

**CSS**

```
.btn-danger {
  background-color: red;
}
.btn-success {
  background-color: green;
}
```

[Modified JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p3kw5xuz/)